# How to pass a value from JS to php functions with out ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a dynamic table with info popups.

here mycode

```
<a id="1" onclick="check(this.id)">

<script type="text/javascript">
function check(value)
{
var result = <?php echo function(value)?>
}
</script>
```

So I need pass an value Which I received from js function to php function.

Please help how to solve it.I dont want to use Ajax or go to other page.

Comment: You cant do that without posting the variable to another page or through ajax since php runs on the server and after it's execution is finished the browser parses the page showing the html/css and running the javascript on the client side.

Comment: The only other way to have a bunch javascript array key/value pairs that would correlate to ids or something in your table...but that is a dumb idea to load all that just so's not to have to use `AJAX`.

Comment: So How can I solve my issuse. please provide an example to solve it.

Comment: There's no way of passing value from js to php (**js -> php**) without using some form of request, either link to another page or ajax request. What @Rasclatt mentioned would be passing data from php to js (**php -> js**) and data would load only on page load, from there php can't affect it until page is reloaded. I really don't see the reason behind not-using ajax.

Comment: can also set the popup data as data attributes in html if data not too large. Overall question is too vague to supply the best solution

Comment: Well all is said. Without Ajax or some even more drastic solution you can not achive this. If this is realy only about info-popups you with limited text you probably should just write it as data tags into html and retrieve it this way later. Infact: What is your problem? Do you don`t know how you could store this info (for the popups) to retrieve it via JS?

Comment: Hi I sloved it bypassing the values from onclick function.

Comment: @rajaking What you're asking for is impossible, so we'd love to see how you solved it. Feel free to post a solution below and mark it accepted to mark this question as "solved".

Comment: I don't think you understand what you're asking. JavaScript is a client side scripting language. PHP is a server side scripting language. PHP is processed, translated into HTML and is passed to the client. So, after a page loads you don't have access to PHP anymore, only HTML and JS. So, like many others have stated, using AJAX helps solve this issue. You can use JQuery to perform an AJAX get request that passes the value from your JS function to a simple PHP API. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP with your function, you'll have to either use AJAX or POST the data and have it display on refresh. However, I don't recommend doing a form submit every time someone clicks a form item.

Ideally, you'd do one of the following:

1. Use JavaScript by itself to run the function and display the result (AngularJS, Backbone, etc. are good for this)
2. Submit the form and it will spit out a result on completion
3. Use AJAX to fill in the item in its place

Answer (score -1):

@meagar I solved this in this way. May be this look some nasty but Ifeel it isok.

```
<a onclick="check('<?php echo nameofphpfunction($myvariable)','<?php echo nameofphpfunction2($myvariable)')" ></a>

<script>
function check(value1,value2)
{
//here I am sending data to my modal popup which is dynamically
$(#heading).text(value1);
$(#content).text(value2);
$(#modal).modal('show');
}
</script>
```

If this helps anyone I would most happy.